# createBlock() and setChild() in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

createBlock() and setChild()

```
difference in magento2
```

Comment: ,have use Tagalys search?.It is good

Answer (score 2):

**`createBlock()`** is used for getting function of your Block file.

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct')->getFunction();
```

**`setChild()`** used for like below,
$pager with set your **`createBlock()`** and set it,

```
$pager = $this->layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\SearchList\Toolbar');
$this->setChild('toolbar_pager',$pager);
```

After setchild you can get it using,

```
$this->getChildHtml('toolbar_pager');
```

Answer (score 1):

### About `createBlock()`

The class used in the parameter is the class of the block you want to create so I reckon you code is okay here.

### About `setChild()`

This method takes two parameters:

- the first one is the name of the child
- the second one is the block itself.

So the `$pager` variable needs to be created using the `createBlock()` method:

```
$pager = $this->layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\SearchList\Toolbar');
```

Comment: @SachinS Well both your custom blocks need to extend the original blocks set in the `di.xml` file

Comment: @SachinS I know you posted it in your question. Your custom blocks need to extend the original `Magento/Catalog` blocks

Comment: Could you please show it how

Comment: @SachinS `class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar` and `class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`